What is wrong with my GET and PUT test commands?
For my CRUD in Django the POST and DELETE tests are working:
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/user/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\": \"john_doe\", \"email\": \"john@example.com\", \"first_name\": \"John\", \"last_name\": \"Doe\"}"
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/user/john_doe/

But for these:
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/user/john_doe/
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8000/user/john_doe/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"email\": \"john.new@example.com\"}"

I get an error.
views.py:
import json
import pymongo
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
database = client['PoseTrack_Database']
users = database['users']


@csrf_exempt
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_data = json.loads(request.body)
        users.insert_one(user_data)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'User created successfully!'}, status=201)


@csrf_exempt
def delete_user(request, username):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        users.delete_one({'username': username})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'User deleted successfully!'}, status=200)


@csrf_exempt
def view_user(request, username):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = users.find_one({'username': username})
        return JsonResponse(data)


@csrf_exempt
def update_user(request, username):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        new_data = json.loads(request.body)
        users.update_one(username, {'$set': new_data})

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', views.create_user),
    path('user/<username>/', views.delete_user),
    path('user/<username>/', views.view_user),
    path('user/<username>/', views.update_user),
]

What's the right command for testing?

It is quite hard to debug if you don't paste the error itself.
Did you first create the object prior to running the GET, PUT commands?

the thing is that what is displaying is not really an error, but is the html code for the website that is shown when I open /user/{username} API. The problem is that the whole page is displaying an error, but a normal one in this context. I get  a Value Error for not having an http response on this page, but that still wouldn't solve my problem

I would try to print out data in your GET request to see what you got back from your database

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against HttpRequest.path_info.
In your case, only the first route; 'user/<username>/' is matched and the only method that the invoked
view handles is 'DELETE' hence all other methods are ignored.
This means that the 'GET' and 'PUT' requests you sent as seen above will be completely ignored. [1]
Completely ignoring a HttpRequest in a Django view is not allowed in Django. Every view must return a HttpResponse.

One possible solution is to use a class based view. It will handle the proper dispatch of requests to their registered views using one route and handling unsupported methods by returning a HttpResponseNotAllowed for those.
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class User(View):

    def post(self, request):
        user_data = json.loads(request.body)
        users.insert_one(user_data)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'User created successfully!'}, status=201)

    def delete(self, request):
        users.delete_one({'username': self.kwargs['username']})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'User deleted successfully!'}, status=200)

    def get(self, request):
        data = users.find_one({'username': self.kwargs['username']})
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def put(self, request):
        new_data = json.loads(request.body)
        users.update_one(self.kwargs['username'], {'$set': new_data})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'User updated successfully!'}, status=200)
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<username>', views.User.as_view(), name="user"),
]

[1] By "completely" I mean completely. Not even a HttpResponseNotAllowed is sent to the client.

Ok, but is there some way to make django go through all my url patterns or I have to give up and find another solution?

The thing is that I tried to put all the conditions for a request in a single view so there will be a single url in the patterns, but it still didn't work. I also tried to switch up the positions of the views in the urlpatterns and none worked then. So, I believe that it's probably something wrong with the code or something of the views, but I cannot seem to find the problem
